# Matlab / Octave and Compass with no arrows and changing line style

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have code that will plot a compass plot in octave (3.2.4) /matlab but how do I get rid of the arrows / change color

```
[x,y]=pol2cart(90*pi/180,1);
compass(x,y)
```

I tried

```
[x,y]=pol2cart(90*pi/180,1);
compass(x,y,'*')
```

and

```
[x,y]=pol2cart(90*pi/180,1);
compass(x,y,'--r')
```

along with several combinations any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the arrows you need to delete all but the first two entries in the `xdata` and `ydata` fields of the plot. The color can be changed by setting the `color` property. Please find below a solution for compass plots with arbitrary numbers of arrows.

```
[x,y]=pol2cart([45 90]*pi/180,1);

h = compass(x,y);

for k = 1:length(h)
    a = get(h(k), 'xdata'); 
    b = get(h(k), 'ydata'); 

    set(h(k), 'xdata', a(1:2), 'ydata', b(1:2), 'color', 'r')
end
```